# rvm install ree complaining about readline on Ubuntu

Tags: rvm, readline, ruby-enterprise-edition, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to install `ree-1.8.7` on Ubuntu 11.10, but I get the following:

```
$ rvm install ree-1.8.7

$ ...
$ ERROR: Error running './installer -a $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03  --dont-install-useful-gems -c --with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr', please read $HOME/.rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/install.log
$ ERROR: There has been an error while trying to run the ree installer. Halting installation.
```

If I check the `install.log` file as suggested, it says that:

> - GNU Readline development headers... not found
>     ...
>     Please run apt-get install libreadline5-dev as root

That didn't work because the package is no longer available, so I finally found out about using `libreadline` from a rvm package. So I install it and run the install again:

```
$ rvm pkg install readline
$ rvm install ree-1.8.7 -C --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

I still get the same error even if I run `rvm remove ree` beforehand.

I'm stuck, what can I do?

UPDATE: I'm still stuck, but I found something that might be useful for others with a similar issue even though it didn't work for me. From the [RVM REE page](http://beginrescueend.com/interpreters/ree/):

> NOTE: on any OS, if installation of REE fails and the output file reports missing readline-devel, zlib-devel, and openssl-devel headers AND you are sure that you have read the packages install instructions - or you are otherwise positive that you have the necessary packages installed in a known location - check your PATH environment variable to make sure something like "/usr/lib" is NOT present. See this [REE issue](http://code.google.com/p/rubyenterpriseedition/issues/detail?id=59&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Summary) for more information. If you don't want to change your PATH variable then this patch fixes the issue in REE 2010.02

I checked my path and all I had that contained `/usr/lib` was `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm`. My full $PATH is this: `bash: /home/michel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/michel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/michel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/michel/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory`.

Comment: What happens if you install the `libreadline6-dev` (which does exist) package instead of the `libreadline5-dev` package that's mentioned?

Comment: @Mike I'll try that, although I installed the suggested libreadline-gplv2-dev and it didn't work.

Comment: @Mike: I installed `libreadline6-dev`, removed any previous `ree` file and try installing again. It seems to have tried to do something with the library, but it still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by running this line:

```
rvm install ree --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Running only `rvm install ree --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr` didn't work, so maybe they all need to be run at the same time.

Note that I ran the following commands some time before succeeding:

```
rvm head update; rvm reload;

# remove any file from previous failed installations
rvm remove ree

# as suggested in a comment on the question
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
```

I'm not sure if the `libreadline6-dev` was necessary, but maybe and it's worth a try if you're having trouble.